# How can i make more realistic lighting/materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Im looking for tips to create more natual looking light like you would get from the sun and tips on making my materials look a little less fake looking the image below is using the glossy and glass shaders but still looks to un-realistic.[image]

Comment: Try use a HDR image texture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4IN4V1SM-A You may also add some Ambient Occlusion in a World tab, since your image is a bit dark.

Comment: One of the biggest issues with computer generated images is that they are too perfect and homogeneous. In the real world things have scratches, dings and many imperfections, on top of dust and signs of wear and tear, discolorations and different kinds of roughness on their textures.  Paying attention to those details will make a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something to be reflected.

If your world is just black, **there is nothing to be reflected by your material**.

As suggested by Gonzou, I'd try a HDR / IBL image.
Alot of those Images can be found here:
http://www.hdrlabs.com/sibl/archive.html

Those will lighty your scene / object and so there is something to be reflected.

---

Speaking of materials i'd suggest this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzXNZkEoTAk

It's quite helpful to get a bit more interesting looking materials.

Comment: Fresnel is pretty important also...